# Accessing member type with `if constexpr` inside generic lambda requires both branches to be well-formed - gcc vs clang

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, sfinae, if-constexpr

Consider two `struct`s with different member type aliases:

```
struct foo { using x = int;   };
struct bar { using y = float; };
```

Given a `T` in a `template` context, I want to get either `T::x` or `T::y` depending on what `T` is:

```
template <typename T>
auto s()
{
    auto l = [](auto p) 
    {
        if constexpr(p) { return typename T::x{}; }
        else            { return typename T::y{}; }
    };

    return l(std::is_same<T, foo>{});
}

int main() 
{ 
    s<foo>(); 
}
```

`g++` compiles the code above, while `clang++` produces this error:

```
error: no type named 'y' in 'foo'
        else            { return typename T::y{}; }
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
note: in instantiation of function template specialization 's<foo>' requested here
    s<foo>();
    ^
```

[**on godbolt.org**, with conformance viewer](https://godbolt.org/g/FiDK6h)

---

**Is `clang++` incorrectly rejecting this code?**

Note that `clang++` accepts the code when removing the indirection through the generic lambda `l`:

```
template <typename T>
auto s()
{
    if constexpr(std::is_same<T, foo>{}) { return typename T::x{}; }
    else                                 { return typename T::y{}; }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work in clang https://wandbox.org/permlink/wUjFv2f0djiOJudV

Comment: Still thinking/investigating as to why

Comment: @Curious: I think that the issue is that the `if constexpr`'s condition depends on the lambda's argument... not sure if I'm correct and why, though.

Comment: I feel the same, but reading into this more in the standard to see if I can understand something

Comment: Also note that using a `struct` instead of a lambda *(i.e. kind-of-equivalent code)* works everywhere: https://godbolt.org/g/PexDHo

Comment: Also, where is the SFINAE here?

Comment: @Curious: poorly-titled question - what I meant is that the `if constexpr` is not acting like its branched were SFINAE-friendly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Richard Smith's post](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/qd3L1-bGg1A%5B26-50%5D) on std-discussion:

> In the implementation I'm familiar with [i.e. Clang], a key problem is that the lexical scopes used while processing a function definition are fundamentally transient, which means that delaying instantiation of some portion of a function template definition is hard to support. Generic lambdas don't suffer from a problem here, because the body of the generic lambda is instantiated with the enclosing function template, [..]

That is, generic lambdas' bodies are partially instantiated using the local context (including template arguments) when the template is instantiated; thus under Clang's implementation, `T::x` and `T::y` are substituted directly, since the closure type could be passed outside. This leads to the failure. As pointed out by @T.C., the code can be considered ill-formed, no diagnostic required, as the instantiation of `s<foo>` yields a template definition (that of the closure) whose second `if constexpr` branch has no well-formed instantiations. This explains the behaviour of both Clang and GCC.

This boils down to an architectural issue in a major implementation (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40243927/3647361); GCC apparently doesn't suffer from this limitation), so I'd be surprised if Core would deem your code well-formed (after all, they accounted for this in the design of generic lambda captures--see the linked answer). GCC supporting your code is, at best, a feature (but probably harmful, since it enables you to write implementation-dependent code).

Comment: What is the corresponding standardise that rules this illformed? I thought that discarded statements are not checked?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I believe there is none. Discarded statements are only discarded statements in the context of the  instantiation of their template. In the surrounding context, they're just code.

Comment: Hmm, I'd go further. After substituting in `T`, one of the branches of the resulting `if constexpr` has no valid specialization, so it's ill-formed NDR by [temp.res]/8. This is probably not intended - see the introduction in P0588R0.

Comment: @T.C. Huh. I didn't know that substatements need to have a valid specialization.

Comment: @T.C. Not sure that argument applies. After all, we're talking about a nested template; there must be a valid specialization over the template arguments of all enclosing templates, and we can certainly provide that.

Comment: Yes, the argument is that the instantiation of `s<foo>` yields, among other things, a template that itself needs to follow [temp.res]/8.

Comment: Well, it by its words applies to all "templates", generated from instantiation or not. Of course, this situation is rather unique...

Comment: @T.C. That interpretation would break tons of code. E.g. [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e8ef4584deb818b) would be ill-formed NDR, because there's some member function `f` that operates on objects of type `T`?

Comment: @T.C. that only applies if the template definition is actually instantiated as a template. Is it here?

Comment: When I reported that "issue" to the committee, they told me that it is not intended that template definitions are ever instantiated as templates. As a result, they fixed explicit instantiation to exclude member templates from being instantiated as templates.

Comment: However in this case of a generic lambda, I agree it looks as though that the lambda body is instantiated as a template, as there is no ondemand instantiation

Comment: @columbo it does not apply to that, because the member template definition is not instantiated, but only the declaration parts.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Where did you report this? Is this a dr?

Comment: @Columbo What Johannes said. The body of `f` isn't instantiated, so the only "template" produced by the instantiation is a declaration of `f`, which is perfectly well-formed. Re the report, I think he's talking about CWG 1532.

Comment: Yes, cwg1532. @t.c. however if you call the member function template in his example, then in order to instantiate the definition, it has to first instantiate the template definition(?). So then the definition exists and causes illformed, NDR (UB). Or am I missing something? Prolly it doesn't matter because it would render an illformed program NDR, but still..

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb In that case [temp.res]/8.1's other condition is not satisfied ("and the template is not instantiated").

Comment: @t.c. I don't see yet why the lambda in this question is illformed NDR tho. There are template parameters for operator() that yield valid specializations of the polymorphic lambda.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb each branch of the `if constexpr` needs to be well-formed for some template parameters of the `operator()`. The second branch is never well-formed.

Comment: @t.c. what rule in the spec says that? Does this mean that `if constexpr(false) void t;` is illformed as well? That would seem to reduce the usability of if constexpr dramatically.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb The same rule in [temp.res]/8.1. And yes.

Comment: @T.C. Ah I see. But I think the second answer should be "it depends", because if the if constexpr is not within a template, then the paragraph doesn't apply. Neither does it apply if the template is instantiated. So I think it won't apply to the question, because the lambda is called (which is kind of weird, I think).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Discarded statements are fully checked outside of templates, so that argument just made it worse. See also https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/stmt.if#2.sentence-3.

Comment: @T.C. wow, I had no idea, thanks (they aren't fully checked tho. Things referenced within discarded statements do not need to be defined).