# Why are local classes not allowed to have template-members?

Tags: c++

Why is this code not allowed?

```
int main()
{
    struct S
    {
        template<bool F>
        void f123()
        {
        }
    };
}
```

My compiler complains, that members of local classes are not allowed to be templates. What's the design decision behind that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Member template in local class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299314/member-template-in-local-class)

Comment: It's weird that this isn't allowed when `auto foo = [](auto test) { return test * test; };` is allowed and that create a closure object with a templated `operator()`

Comment: This is a part of C++ since time immemorial. Used to be about linkage and templates. Then the linkage bit was relaxed and lambdas became generic to boot. This is just something no one revisited since.